# Prevent / Postpone loading of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In developing my portfolio, I realised it takes a long-time for the page to load as all the images have to load in order for the page-load to be complete.

So, I was wondering if there is a way, any way, to prevent or stop the loading and then allow it later on.

Meaning something like, prevent the loading immediately and then on click of another element that had loaded, lets say #title, then load .images.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You want people to have to click some kind of placeholder to see your content? That seems like a terrible user experience.

Comment: I don't know how many images you have and what size they are , but I think youre going about it wrong , maybe reduce the  size of the images, and maybe you don't need hundreds, or however many pictures are making the page slow

Comment: @meagar yes, that does seem like a horrible UX. But thats not what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ScottSelby I have already optimised them. Problem is that I have 80 or so images.

Comment: Also note: Unless you're doing something very strange, you shouldn't have the problem you're describing. Browsers will not wait for all images to download before they start rendering a page.

Comment: Are you using thumbnails that link to the larger images or actually loading 80 (or so) large images?

Comment: @meagar no, it is rendering the page. The page rendering is just happening very slowly.

Comment: @BillyMoat they are large images that are resized to small images via css.

Comment: @IrfanM - That's generally considered very bad practice because it causes precisely the problem you're asking about here. You would really be better off creating small thumbnail images that link to the larger images.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need 80 full size high quality images displayed on the initial page load, thumbnails should be separate images that are smaller sized, not just re-adjusting the size through css.  Why can't you use some type of paging, or slides , or thumbnail, or something

Comment: @BillyMoat I did not know that was bad practice, okay I will go with thumbnails.

Comment: @ScottSelby I don't. I did it that way because I didn't know it was bad practice. I will use one of the alternatives instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML

```
<img src="" class="lazyload" data-attr="image1.jpg" alt="Alt" title="Title" width="50" height="50" />
```

Jquery

```
$('#title').click(function(){
    $('.lazyload').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-attr'));
    });
});
```

Or you could use the [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin for slightly different functionality.

Comment: hmm this looks interesting. So what this does is does is load the image element, but not the source (as there is no value for the src yet). 
And then on click of #title, the value for the source attribute is added, which means it is then loaded, correct?

Comment: wait, one question. It doesn't validate, because it says the src must have a value. Will the script still work, though?

Comment: Remove the `src` attribute then (or put the URL of a 1x1 transparent .gif). The JavaScript will work regardless.